# Not understanding higher order functions in Javascript. Receiving an error

Tags: javascript, higher-order-functions

I am trying to make this program use these functions to print N number of perfect powers with the use of higher order functions. I've stumped myself, and now when I print my function, I get an array of NaN that is the length of my 'P' input. It functions closely to what I need but I can't get around the error. Any help would be appreciated.

An example of the output would be if I entered:
perfectpower(5,3); I would see:

5, 25, 125

```
   power = (N, P) => {

    return Math.pow(N, P);
}


function each(A, func) {

    for (var i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        A[i] = func(A[i]);
    }
    return A;
}


function sequence(N) {

    return Array(N).fill().map((_, idx) => idx + 1)

}


perfectpower = (N, P) => {

    return (each(sequence(P), power))

}

console.log(perfectpower(5,3));
console.log(sequence(5))
console.log(power(5,2))
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const power = (N) => (P) => {

    return Math.pow(N, P);
}


function each(A, func) {

    for (var i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        A[i] = func(A[i]);
    }
    return A;
}


function sequence(N) {

    return Array(N).fill().map((_, idx) => idx + 1)

}


const perfectpower = (N, P) => {

    return (each(sequence(P), power(N)))

}

console.log(perfectpower(5,3));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing `N` through this chain, so `Math.pow` is ultimately only getting one of the two arguments it needs. I see as I was typing this, someone else posted the code to accomplish what you need.

Comment: Thank you so much, I understand now.

Answer (score 0):

You did not pass the second argument when calling `func()` which is the `power` function which requires 2 parameters that's why it's producing `NaN` values.

```js
  power = (N, P) => {

    return Math.pow(N, P);
}


function each(A, func, pow) {

    for (var i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        A[i] = func(A[i], pow);
    }
    return A;
}


function sequence(N) {

    return Array(N).fill().map((_, idx) => idx + 1)

}


perfectpower = (N, P) => {

    return (each(sequence(N), power, P))

}

console.log(perfectpower(5,3));
console.log(sequence(5))
console.log(power(5,2))
```